# Migrating only selected accounts to new machine

Tags: 16.04, migration, accounts

I am working on upgrading the hardware used for our mail/ftp server from an old 32 bit platform to a much newer 64 bit platform.  Both are running Ubuntu 16.04.03.  Getting all of the appropriate packages installed on the new system has been accomplished.  Now I need to transfer the USER accounts/groups ONLY to the new machine.  I don't want to just copy the old system's passwd, shadow, group and gshadow files because many of the uid/gid numbers are different on the new system.  Once I get the user accounts migrated, I will start on moving all package settings (not looking forward to that!)

My question has several parts:

1. Is it "safe" to copy individual records from the old files into the new ones?
2. Is there a better way to do what I need than manually copying each individual record?
3. Are the four files I listed the only ones I need to modify, or are there others?
4. What purpose do the files named like 'gshadow-' serve?

EDIT:  Perhaps I should add that I am currently transferring the entire /home folder tree from the old system to the new, which is why I want to keep all of the existing uid/gid values.  Luckily, they are all well above those created by installing packages so the user's uid/gid values don't conflict with anything on the new machine.  I only have about a dozen, but they are virtually computer illiterate, so I am not allowed to either change their passwords nor tell them to provide me with new ones.  That's why I need to transfer their existing records across.

I would have just cloned the drive and moved the image, but I wanted to use the additional memory that moving to 64 bit allowed.

EDIT2:  It appears that there are a set of vi tools (vipw and vigr) that may be used to manually edit the files -- if I can only figure out how to use vi enough to do that.  Sigh.  The "vi way" has always been utterly, totally alien to me to the point that it is even difficult to comprehend the documentation and tutorials.  Hopefully, I can just use an editor I understand and then have vi delete everything and paste in the entire updated file content.

Comment: I would myself use the generic migration methods (example: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/ ) and renew the user id on the new server if you want to (example script to change user id: https://pastebin.com/2Hfm4VgK )

Comment: Thanks for the link to the faq, it is similar to what I tried but much more automated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it "safe" to copy individual records from the old files into the
   new ones?

Apparently, since my system is still working and all migrated accounts are now accessible.

2. Is there a better way to do what I need than manually copying each
   individual record?

Probably, the link provided by @Rinzwind ([Move or migrate user accounts from old Linux server to a new Linux server | nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/)) shows how to use command line tools to automate the user account transfer ... mostly. (smile)

3. Are the four files I listed the only ones I need to modify, or are
   there others?

It seems that group, gshadow, passwd and shadow are the only files that need modifying, though any other user-specific things such as home and mail folders would also need to be transferred.

4. What purpose do the files named like 'gshadow-' serve?

I did not figure this one out, but I believe they are backups of the previous version. I asked because I was concerned that they might, somehow, be used to ensure the integrity of the shadow files to protect them from manual modifications, but they are not used for that.

---

To make my changes, I used the WinMerge tool on my Windows desktop to compare the old/new files and selectively move only the lines I needed across from old to new.  Then I used the sudo vipw/vigr commands to edit the files on the new system.  Surprisingly, I was asked what editor I wanted to use when I started the first one, so I picked nano, which I understand enough to delete the old and paste the entire modified content into.  I rebooted after changing all four and the migrated user accounts are working.